# XCode can't find GCC

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc

After i updated iPhone SDK to 4.1 I can no longer compile neither for Simulator or Device. I get the following message:

```
error: can't exec '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' (No such file or directory)
```

Solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if it is there and accessible, `sudo ls -l /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.  Mine has these permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  166128 Jul 26 15:05 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

Have you tried reinstalling yet?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling. gcc-4.2 isn't even found in the folder by ls :( Can I add it manually somehow or is it a special version for iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me. So for xcode 3.2.5:

1. gcc-4.2 is definitely installed by
   the installer. ie:

   ls /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g* =>

> ```
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0
> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
> ```

1. Randomly linking in the gcc-4.2 from
   the /usr/bin directory is just asking for trouble. That's not the gcc that is part of the xcode package - who knows if it is really the same version.
2. Reinstalling fixed it for me,
   although I was finding that
   particular install flakey.